# Display text below textfield and adding background color

Tags: html, css

If we visit [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) you can see `Add Review` tab , please click on that. than you can see as below image.

we are displaying `Maximum 60 characters`, `your rating` & `first and last name` after textfield, but I want to display below text field. also I want to add white background for section.

[image]

I want to display like below image :

[image]

```
<li class="inline-label">
                        <label for="summary_field" class="required"><em></em><?php echo $this->__('Review Title :') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">

                            <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getTitle()) ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <p>( Maximum 60 characters )</p>
                   </li>


                    <li>
                        <label for="review_field" class="required"><em></em><?php echo $this->__('Your Review :') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getDetail()) ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <p>( Please make sure your review contains atleast 100 characters )</p>
                    </li>
```

**css**

```
.fieldset p {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

review-list .srka-rating-code .label {
    min-width: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: add `p` tag into your `input-box` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your description `p` tag into your `input-box` div like this:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="">
   <p>( Maximum 60 characters )</p>
</div>
```

For Background color:

```
.tab-text {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;   
    padding: 60px 30px 30px;
}
.input-box textarea{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

For row layout add all field in `li` tag like this:

```
<li>
    <label>Your Rating :</label>
    <div class="input-box">
        your field like ( input or textarea)
        <p> Description Text</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: please help me for `your rating` section , it should display from left as in image  and help me to add background-color for section as in image

Comment: please help me to display `your review` textbox as same length as above textbox , same for Name box also.

Comment: background-color working fine, please help me for `your rating` section to display as in image

Comment: in front of `your rating` stars are there, but its not displaying, can you please help why stars are not displaying?

Comment: I have update my code .. please follow this for all fields

Comment: for 3rd part, i am really not getting what to do, is there chnace to fix this only with css ?

Comment: `#srka-product-review-list.input-box{border: medium none !important;
    padding: 5px 0 !important;}` try this

Comment: i updated your code, now box is removed, can you please check why those `stars` are not displaying there

Comment: you can check here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/1rrQ3.png instead of stars its displaying square boxes when we click on image.

Comment: thanks, i wil check it, please help me to display `Your Rating` part to left side as in image.

Comment: also i want to make proper alignment as in image that all lines should start from same place. also textboxes should have same length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116668/discussion-between-mukesh-ram-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS 3 property background-size:

```
#background {
background-size: 100% auto; /* width and height, can be %, px or whatever. */
}
```